# Concatenate a string with the output of a php function as a parameter of anouther function

Tags: php

When I call a function `mainfunc()` I want to put an explicit value near to the output of a function as a parameter of `mainfunc()`. I want to do someting like `mainfunc('foo'.LaTeX());`.

But, when I do that, I get the output of `LaTeX()` before “foo”, it exactly print me `LaTeXfoo` (the output of `LaTeX()` is `LaTeX`) and I got the same thing when I try to permute it like `LaTeX() . foo`.

So, this is the deffinition of the function `LaTeX()` :

```
function LaTeX()
{
    ?><span class="latex">L<spu>a</sup>T<sub>e</sub>X</span><?php
}
```

So, what can I do to make `mainfunc` exactly receive `fooLaTeX` by using `LaTeX()` function, please?

Comment: This should be moved to http://tex.stackexchange.com/ or StackOverflow.

Comment: in Latex() function use return instead of printing!

Comment: StackOverflow, sure. But tex no, because it is a question about PHP, I use a PHP command to print the name of LaTeX correctly formatted but it could be another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple:

Don't print (which is what happens if you close the PHP code and reopen).

The following two lines of code will essentially do the same thing (they're equivalent):

```
echo '<b>Hello World!</b>';

?><b>Hello World!</b><?php
```

Instead, work with return values:

```
function LaTeX()
{
    return '<span class="latex">L<sup>a</sup>T<sub>e</sub>X</span>';
}
```

This will create the behavior you're looking for. However, if you just plan on returning a fixed string, better define a constant:

```
define(LaTeX, '<span class="latex">L<sup>a</sup>T<sub>e</sub>X</span>');

mainfunc('foo' . LaTeX);
```